# How to Insert multiple columns data into table containing single column using cursor in pl/sql?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert data from table 1 to another table using cursor and purpose is to understand objects in Oracle.

However, I'm getting error like "*Invalid no. of arguments*" while inserting data using cursor loop.

```
create type airport_t as object
 (
     Rank number,
     Airport varchar2(80),
     Location varchar2(60),
     Country varchar2(50),
     Code_iata varchar2(3),
     Code_icao varchar2(4),
     Total_Passenger number,
     Rank_change number,
     Percent_change number
  );


   create table AIRPORTS2017OO
   (
       AIRPORT airport_t   // Look above code..
    );


    declare
    cursor insert_cr is select * from AIRPORTS2017;
    begin
       open insert_cr;
       for i in insert_cr  
       loop
           insert into Airports2017oo values( airport_t(i.Rank || '    
            '||i.airport ||'    '||
             i.Location ||'    '|| i.Country ||'    '|| i.code_iata ||'  '|| 
            i.code_icao ||'   '||
         i.Total_Passenger ||'   '|| i.Rank_change ||'    '|| 
         i.Percent_change));
        end loop;

       end;
        /
```

Table 1 contains 50 rows and 9 columns. However, table 2 has only 1 column and I want all data from table 1 into table 2 in single column only.

**Error image:**[1]

Comment: It's still throwing error saying "Inconsistent data type". Is that due to table 2 has only single column??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column in the AIRPORTS2017OO table is of type AIRPORT_T. The AIRPORT_T type, meanwhile, has a number of different parameters of various types. However, when inserting the row you are concatenating all fields into a single string to pass as a single parameter. You need to either pass them as separate parameters, or redefine your object type as having a single VARCHAR2 attribute. If the former is correct, the following should work.

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR insert_cr IS
      SELECT * FROM airports2017;
BEGIN
   FOR i IN insert_cr LOOP
      INSERT INTO airports2017oo
      VALUES
         (airport_t(i.rank
                   ,i.airport
                   ,i.location
                   ,i.country
                   ,i.code_iata
                   ,i.code_icao
                   ,i.total_passenger
                   ,i.rank_change
                   ,i.percent_change));
   END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Also, see [Oracle Object-Relational Developer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adobj/object-methods.html#GUID-52304F42-33D7-423E-9CB2-7641FAA25D52) for details on the system-defined constructor.

Comment: You don't even need the cursor for loop, it can (should!) be done in a single insert-as-select statement, e.g. see https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hh5kysr2broe4887p8w3feav5 for a cut-down demo.

Comment: @Boneist True! Thank you for pointing it out. I decided to focus on the syntax issue rather than dive into best practice/optimization discussion.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @I_am_Vits Please accept the answer if this helped.